# How to change the background image of a button using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, button, background-image

I want to change the background image of a button using Javascript. Here is what I am currently trying, but it is failing.

HTML code -

```
      <tr id="Rank1">
              <td><button class="darkSquare"></button></td>
               <td><button class="lightSquare" ></button></td>
                <td><button class="darkSquare" ></button></td>
               <td><button class="lightSquare" ></button></td>
                <td><button id="e1" class="darkSquare" ></button></td>
                <td><button class="lightSquare" ></button></td>
                <td><button class="darkSquare" ></button></td>
                <td><button class="lightSquare"> </button></td>
            </tr>
```

JavaScript Code

```
        initializer();

        function initializer()
         {
           var tableRow = document.getElementById("Rank1");

           var buttons = tableRow.getElementsByTagName("button");

           for(b in buttons)
            {
               console.log(b.toString());
               b.style.backgroundImage = "url('darkSquare.jpg')";
            }
         }
```

In the console, I get an error saying b.style is undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for (... in ...)` loops do not work that way in JavaScript it should be:

```
for (var b = 0; b < buttons.length; b++) {
    buttons[b].style.backgroundImage = "url('darkSquare.jpg')";
}
```

`for (... in ...)` actually iterates over all the "members" of an object

eg. using `var x = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}` in `for(var m in x) console.log(m)` will produce

```
> a
> b
> c
```

it kind of works with arrays because it considers the indices members like this:

```
var x = [1,2,3];
for (var m in x) console.log(m);
> 0
> 1
> 2
```

since it is giving you the indices as if they were members you can't distinguish. the pitfall is:

```
var x = [1,2,3];
x.stuff = 'boo!';
for (var m in x) console.log(m);
> 0
> 1
> 2
> stuff
```

**General Rule of Thumb**: only use `for (... in ...)` when iterating over members in an object, use `for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)` when using arrays

*you can always cheat and use*:

```
for (var i = 0, item = x[i]; i < x.length; item=x[++i]) {
    // now item is the current item
}
```

Comment: Yes. This worked, but why didn't the for in loop work? What was I doing wrong there?

Comment: Oh. So in arrays the indices are considered as members. Hmmm. Very helpful.

Comment: `for (var b in buttons) buttons[b].style...` but this doesn't say what you think it does read my edited comment above^  but what it breaks down to is `for (... in ...)` isn't an iterator like it is in other languages (java, c#, etc...)

Comment: because I added `.stuff` as an expando member to the object that is of the type `Array` in the line `x.stuff = 'boo!';`, remember ALL JavaScript objects support expando properties.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your loop as so

```
for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
{
   buttons[i].style.backgroundImage = "url('darkSquare.jpg')";
}​
```

The loop you used assign keys in a variable b. Since you didn't use the hasOwnProperty function, this loop can also yield other data you might not want.

You could also use the for-in loop as so

```
for(var b in buttons)
{
    if (buttons.hasOwnProperty(b))
        buttons[b].style.backgroundImage = "url('darkSquare.jpg')";
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

when using `for ( ... in .... )` the first parameter is the key in the array so you have to use it like this:

```
for( b in buttons ) {
    buttons[b].style.backgroundImage = "url('darkSquare.jpg')";
}
```

working example in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/teneff/aDgPv/)